# String to variable name without eval

Tags: javascript, string, variables, eval

I want to know if there is any way to convert a string to a var name without using eval.

I have the following json declared in a file:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "usr_language": {"var": "this.$i18n.locale", "value": null},
        "token": {"var": "googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token", "value": null}
    }
}
```

When I import inside the component, I want to access `fields.usr_language.alias`.

Without using eval it returns the string “this.$i18n.locale”, obviously. Is there any way to get without using eval to get the values in variables? Is it unsafe to use eval in this cases?

Comment: Why is it a string in the first place?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. So, if your *text* does not match your actual code, you will start getting runtime syntax and/or reference errors. And since this is text, you cannot even use any of the wide-spread tools to check that for correctness.

Comment: I can,t put the var name in the json file

Comment: There is no real way of doing it and eval is going to have issues with scope.

Comment: @VLAZ i do it that way because i want to have dynamic schemas that can interact with my app

Comment: you need to use `eval`, because you can not access the variable with a value in a variable outside of the global scope.

Comment: @h3rm3s why not just have your variables as properties of some object?

Comment: @VLAZ you say like have this vars in a global object and access them by name in json file?

Comment: @h3rm3s use an object *instead* of `this`. Just have something like `myVariables = { $i18n: { locale: "en" }}` and keep adding those there, then pick up the string and follow the path to get the property.

Comment: @h3rm3s Anytime you think you need to manage variable names dynamically at runtime you are doing it wrong. This is why we have things like Maps and Objects.

Comment: @VLAZ aha, i get the point, i think this is going to do the trick. I was in all this mess 'cause i need some generic

Comment: Where do those expressions come from and why do they need to be in a JSON file? Whether they are safe to `eval` depends on who controls the code.

Comment: @Bergi that way i generate object dynamically based on schemas, my data depend on db name fields, there isn't any name hardcoded, so i never touch the code if something in db change

Comment: @Bergi i don't know if is the correct way, simply i implemented that way

Comment: So you are storing those expressions in the database as well? Also, I don't see any reason why you couldn't serialise an object with methods (`{
        usr_language: {var() { return this.$i18n.locale; }, value: null},
        token: {var() { return googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token; }, value: null}
    }`) instead of JSON.

Comment: Ok @Bergi i think that is a good solution for what i m looking, 
in which I had not thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve this by creating a function dynamicly, but it has the same issuse like eval.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://www.educative.io/answers/eval-vs-function-in-javascript

I have the name of an array in string form and wanted to get the array with the same name. Eval() works but is "evil" and should/must be avoided. Using Function() worked.

```
  const thisFileName = "aStringOfSomeFileName";
  const arrayName = "someString";

  eval(arrayName);
```

This worked instead:

```
 const categoryArray = Function("return " + arrayName)();
```

Then I could get the object I wanted from inside the array I was looking for:

```
 const indexOfObject = categoryArray.findIndex(object => {
            return object.filename === thisFileName;
        });
```